# getting the value from gridview

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with Gridview and two buttons one for ADD and other for SHOW IMAGES

```
int Id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
```

The above code is working when I used it on the ADD button CLICK event.
But when I used it on SHOW IMAGES CLICK event, it is giving error

> There is no row at position 0

Comment: This sounds like a timing issue. When are you making this call? It's possible the code above is executing before the data is loaded to your GridView.

Comment: Try to use `if(GridView.Rows.Count > 0){// TODO}` to check if GridView is empty.

Comment: Gridview loads with data on Form Load.

Answer (score 0):

When you drop a button on a gridview (or even a listview), the built in buttons such as add, or edit etc.  they have two attributes.

the "name" of the CommandName is VERY, but VERY VERY VERY important here.

If you use "Select", or "Edit"? then the grid view WILL FIRE:
(GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged)

However, if you use any custom name, then the GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged will NOT fire, but the GridView1_RowCommand WILL fire! And keep in mind that when this event fires with a custom CommandName, then SelectedIndex does NOT fire.

So, you can drop in a button like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
     <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField>
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Select" 
                        CommandName="ViewPictures"
                        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' 
                />
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

Note as stated, with a button (or link button - don't matter), then because our CommandName is NOT a built in one (Select, Edit etc.), then the row command event will fire.

So, our code can be this:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand

    If e.CommandName = "ViewPictures" Then

        Debug.Print("row pk value = " & e.CommandArgument.ToString)

        ' grid view Selected index event will NOT fire - index will NOT change.
        ' we do have PK above, so we can run code on PK value - do what we want based on PK

        ' Now if we really do need the whole row?
        ' then this from the bottom of the ocean horror story from develoeprs with
        ' damaged brains will get you the row

        Dim gvRow As GridViewRow = CType(CType(e.CommandSource, Control).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
        ' so now, you can go say:
        Debug.Print("Row from grid seleted index = " & gvRow.RowIndex)


    End if
End Sub
```

Note how the PK id (or whatever you pass) should suffice. However, the above code also includes the whack code that will also give you the whole row if you wish.

In many cases, I often just drop a button, set commandName="Select", and with only one button on the row - who cares? The SelectedIndex event fires, and VERY OFTEN we don't care which button - since often it is only one button.

If you start to drop in extra buttons, then shift the code over to GridView1_RowCommand. That way you can pick up the CommandName for custom code.

Just keep in mind that RowCommand allows you to pass a value, and if you really need the row, then the sample code will allow you to pick up the row if you need more then say one value passed.

The row code in C# would be say this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
if (e.CommandName == "ViewPictures")
{
    Debug.Print("row pk value = " + e.CommandArgument.ToString);

    // grid view Selected index event will NOT fire - index will NOT change.
    // we do have PK above, so we can run code on PK value - do what we want based on PK

    // Now if we really do need the whole row?
    // then this from the bottom of the ocean horror story from develoeprs with
    // damaged brains will get you the row

    GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)(Control)e.CommandSource.NamingContainer;
    // so now, you can go say:
    Debug.Print("Row from grid seleted index = " + gvRow.RowIndex);
}
}
```

Events for GridView

[image]

Comment: I do not have BUTTON on GRIDVIEW. All are separate controls on a form. I have GRIDVIEW  and SHOWIMAGE button and LISTBOX. On Form Load GRIDVIEW is loaded with data. When I click on GRIDVIEW ROW the LISTBOX shows the ImageId's it contain. After I click on gridviewrow on GRIDVIEW  when I click on SHOWIMAGE button. Image linked to that ID which I am getting from gridvew , should display on a separate form.

Comment: Absolute ZERO reason as to not using a ImageButton. All of the above will work exaclty the same if you drop in a imagebutton on that gridview And if you ONLY have a image button, and not multiple buttons? Then set command argument="Select", and you don't have to use the rowcommand button, but can use the better and preferred Selected index change event. So, zero reason why you can't use all of the above information outlined. As noted, this will work fine with a imagebutton, and NOTE careful you have a choice of which event to use (RowCommand or SelectedIndexChanged).

Comment: I do not see RowCommand Event in EventsList for GRIDVIEW

Comment: You should - see the screen shot I added to the end of my post.

Comment: Sir, I do not see RowCommand Event. I am not able to add screenshot to show you.

Comment: You noted you are using asp.net webforms. So you can view your page as markup, or you can click on design, and view the web page with a visual designer. Perhaps you not actually using webforms and using MVC then?

Comment: Sir,I am using WindowsForm

Comment: Ah, ok - well your tag is asp.net, and that means web development. I mean, you must have wondered about all  the markup HTML code then, right? So, you NOT using asp.net - major confusing then. So, you using winforms, and not web forms. But you not only tagged this question as asp.net, but ALSO included webforms, and not winforms. So asp.net = web only applications. And WebForms = web forms, not desktop. So, if you using windows forms - the event model is quite a bit different. And of course the difference between web and desktop is about the same difference between a dog and a helicopter.